# Properly Populate Html Table with JSON

Tags: jquery, json

I have this code to recieve json data from php

```
        $.getJSON("../controller/testController.php",{action:"one"}, function(data)
        {
            var datas = "";
        $.each(data, function(key,value)
        {
            datas += "<tr>";
                datas += "<td>"+value.data1+"</td>";
                datas += "<td>"+value.data2+"</td>";
                datas += "<td>"+value.data3+</td>";                     
            datas += "</tr>";
        })
            $(".tables").append(datas);
        })
```

This is the html

```
<table class="tables">
<thead>
<th>1</th>
<th>2</th>
<th>3</th>
</thead>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Why i cant select the data ? im checking it with this code. Is there a better way to do this?
**NOTE:** With static data i can select it.

```
$('.tables tbody tr td').last().css("background","cyan");
```

**UPDATE**

Doing some coding i saw that if i put the "css" code inside the getJSON function, i can do the job. But doing it like this, ill cant make any manipulation of the data outside of the function (horrible coding). Any ideas to make this better?

Comment: what do you mean with `Why can't I select the data`? You're using a script for that? Maybe because you're checking it asynchronously and before the ajax request has been fulfilled? Show us the full code please

Comment: Check if you are selecting the data before they are rendered with json

Comment: when i render the table, if use .css to select the td, nothing happen. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have a typo in the line :
    `datas += "<td>"+value.data3</td>";`

It should be :
   `datas += "<td>" + value.data3 + "</td>";`

Comment: hello, thanks for the tip. but still cant select the td

Comment: Try to log datas before appending it to table, like this :  `console.log(datas);`

Comment: i did it, but still i cant select any data of the table with .css

Comment: i think the "append" method data can not be manipulated. maybe?

Comment: Is there any data displayed in the console when you're logging ?

Comment: Also try appending to tbody instead, like this :  ` $(".tables tbody").append(datas);`

Comment: when i do console log, it shows the data. Also with $(".tables tbody").append(datas); nothings happens. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: make sure you're changing the background ONLY after the call to the controller

Comment: I don't see any update..is it working ? also try selecting like this :  `$("table  tbody")` if you have only one table on the page.

Comment: check my main post, there i explain how "the jobs its done", but i think thats a bad bad practice. i think getjson function its the problem (make the data "unchangeble")

Comment: Why would you want to manipulate the data outside of that function ? I'm not sure I see your point...

Comment: Because i want to make others methods like on blur,keyup etc etc. That wil be a problem all together inside getjson data ?

Answer (score 0):

it's typing mistake.

instead of `datas += "<td>"+value.data3</td>";`

it should be `datas += "<td>"+value.data3+"</td>";`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aozcp800/)

Comment: hello, thanks for the tip. but still cant select the td

Answer (score 0):

**This is the code to solve the problem.**

```
$.getJSON("../controller/testController.php",{action:"one"}, function(data)
{
    var datas = "";
$.each(data, function(key,value)
{
    datas += "<tr>";
        datas += "<td>"+value.data1+"</td>";
        datas += "<td>"+value.data2+"</td>";
        datas += "<td>"+value.data3+</td>";                     
    datas += "</tr>";
})
    $(".tables").append(datas);
    $('.tables tbody tr td').last().css("background","cyan");
})
```

Putting the "css" code inside the getJSON